# Powershell if condition returning no results when some exist

Tags: powershell

The code block below executes without the CSV being generated suggesting it has no return. However the conditions given are definitely valid for at least one object.

A Mail Enabled Security group in O365 has the "SecurityEnabled" property set to true, the "MailEnabled" property set to true and the property "GroupTypes" is an empty array? string? "{}" whatever the curly brackets are supposed to represent but they're empty.

```
$Groups = Get-MgGroup -Property "Members" -All
foreach($group in $Groups){
    if ( (($group.SecurityEnabled) -and ($group.MailEnabled)) -and ($group.GroupTypes -ne 'Unified')){
        $members = Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId $group.Id
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Display Name' = $group.DisplayName
            'Members' = $members.AdditionalProperties.displayName -join ";"
        } | Export-Csv -path "$OutputFolder\MailEnabledSecurityGroups.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
    }
    continue
}
```

Comment: if you remove the `Export-Csv` statement, do you see output being displayed to your console? is `$OutputFolder` actually defined in your code?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Nope get no return at all not even a blank line :L. Yep I define $OutputFolder elsewhere in my script as a repo for all my reports. Others have worked this is the only exception

Comment: Change your last condition, because `GroupTypes` is an array property, use this instead: `... -and 'Unified' -notin $group.GroupTypes) { ...`

Comment: Swapped the Export-Csv for a Write-Output on its own like so;

[PSCustomObject]@{
            'Display Name' = $group.DisplayName
            'Members' = $members.AdditionalProperties.displayName -join ";"
        } | Write-Output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GroupTypes` property from the `MicrosoftGraphGroup` instance is an array, in this case you want to use [containment operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#containment-operators), more specifically `-notin` or `-notcontains`, the condition would look like:

```
# with `-notcontains`
if ($group.SecurityEnabled -and $group.MailEnabled -and $group.GroupTypes -notcontains 'Unified') {

# with `-notin`
if ($group.SecurityEnabled -and $group.MailEnabled -and 'Unified' -notin $group.GroupTypes) {
```

As for why it was not working before, `-ne` and `-eq` can act as a filter when the LHS (left hand side) of the comparison is an array and because `$group.GroupTypes` was an empty array, the comparison returned `null` and the `if` condition evaluated to `false` because of this.

```
$obj = [pscustomobject]@{
    GroupTypes = @()
}
$obj.GroupTypes -ne 'Unified' # => null

$obj = [pscustomobject]@{
    GroupTypes = @('something else')
}
$obj.GroupTypes -ne 'Unified' # => something else
```

As aside, it's probably a better idea to export the output all at once instead of *appending* to the CSV file on each loop iteration (Disk I/O is expensive and will slow down your script a lot!):

```
Get-MgGroup -Property "Members" -All | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.SecurityEnabled -and $_.MailEnabled -and 'Unified' -notin $_.GroupTypes) {
        $members = Get-MgGroupMember -GroupId $_.Id

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Display Name' = $_.DisplayName
            'Members'      = $members.AdditionalProperties.displayName -join ";"
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv -path "$OutputFolder\MailEnabledSecurityGroups.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Filtering on Azure side may increase the speed of your code and also reduce the amount of conditions being evaluated on client side:

```
Get-MgGroup -Property "Members" -Filter "securityEnabled eq true and mailenabled eq true" | ForEach-Object {
    if ('Unified' -notin $_.GroupTypes) {
        # code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding my pipe to the end of my existing code doesn't work, returns as an empty pipe element is not allowed.

Comment: @AlistairTrout that's correct, this is because `foreach` (the loop), is a [language keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-7.2) and you can't pipe after them (any of them). This is why I'm using `ForEach-Object` in my code (which allows this) :)

Comment: Nevermind retried pipe works now - however the results are the same values duplicated for the ammount of items in the object. The results aren't updated to the export

Comment: How would I increase the speed? Using your method doesn't give me the correct data, I get the right number of rows, but the data is all duplicated. Would be good if I could speed up the entire process as running on tenants with 10,000 users plus currently :/

Happy to share the full script on a separate post?

Comment: @AlistairTrout oh my, that was my bad :( I forgot to update to `'Display Name' = $_.DisplayName` try again with the updated answer. As for speeding it up, you could use the filter: `-Filter "securityEnabled eq true and mailenabled eq true"` to filter on Azure side. That would remove 2 conditions from your code and should make it faster. There may be other ways to increase even more the speed but that should be asked on a new question